# Не работает debugger в RubyMine 7.1.5 (Frame is not available)

Tags: ruby

Я только начал изучение руби и программы рубимайн, но по какой-то причине деббагер не видит ниодного фрейма, вот так выглядит http://prntscr.com/ij0mvr

В видео гайде, кроме установки гема ни слова не было, можете подсказать, что делать?